# Obtaining user location not functioning in Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, google-maps, userlocation

Good evening, I am trying to allow users to locate themselves on a map. When I run the app and access my google maps view, I get the error message "this app has attempted to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description. The app's Info.plist must contain an “NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription” key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data" and the map is set a default state.

I have put

```
<key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app needs your current location</string>
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app needs your current location</string>
```

in my info.plist, but it tells me that I need to put in NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription in order to access location. I already have put it in and it still won't show the user location! Am I leaving something out or is this a bug? it worked fine for me before I updated to the newest version of Xcode.

My code that enables google maps is as follows,

```
  func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    let location = locations.last
    let lat = (location?.coordinate.latitude)!
    let long = (location?.coordinate.longitude)!
    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: lat, longitude: long, zoom: 17.0)

    self.myMapView.animate(to: camera)

    showPartyMarkers(lat: lat, long: long)
}


func initGoogleMaps() {
    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: 40.014281, longitude: -83.030914, zoom: 17.0)
    self.myMapView.camera = camera
    self.myMapView.delegate = self
    self.myMapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true
}
    func viewController(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController, didAutocompleteWith place: GMSPlace) {
    let lat = place.coordinate.latitude
    let long = place.coordinate.longitude

    showPartyMarkers(lat: lat, long: long)

    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: lat, longitude: long, zoom: 17.0)
    myMapView.camera = camera
    txtFieldSearch.text=place.formattedAddress
```

Comment: Did you start CoreLocation ?

Comment: @ktrkathir I have it called in my imports, but I never programmed anything for it. I will question to show my code for google maps.

Comment: If you using simulator. enable debug location

Comment: @ktrkathir I updated my code above to show how i implemented gmaps

Answer (score 0):

Add new records in your new InfoPlist.strings file.

```
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>app need your location for finding a place</string>

add  lines in viewdidload

locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
```

delete your app from simulator and run again.

Comment: I am running this on my phone that way I can access true user location. I deleted and reinstalled still the same problem.

Comment: Check location permission on setting.

Comment: I changed it to always and I'm still getting the message. My app doesn't send the notification to allow or deny it.

Answer (score 0):

Add below keys in plist.

```
Privacy - Location Always and When In Use Usage Description

Privacy - Location When In Use Usage Description
```

EDIT

I am not seeing Initialisation for **locationManager.**

Use below code to initialise:

```
   /// CLLocationManager object
   var locationManager: CLLocationManager = {
        let manager = CLLocationManager()
        manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        return manager
    }()
```

After Init start updating location, for that add below lines in viewDidload

```
locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
```

Comment: @Toseefkhiliji am I missing anything else?/

Comment: @zachwilcox: Updated answer, delete your app from simulator and run again.

Comment: I already those lines in my code. I'm still getting the same errors.

Comment: I have tried many fixes but it still says I need to update my info plist. I have the above lines inserted already and I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Updated answer, please check device location service permission also.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer after reposting the question. If anyone is having this issue as well, what you want to do is click on your projects target build settings, click on info (Left of build settings) and you want to make sure the Custom iOS Target Properties have the same info as your regular p-list. If it does not, simply click the plus sign, and add them in. This should fix the problem because it has with mine. I hope you all find this useful.